# How can I by VBA code see that outlook object is closed

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook.application

I use Outlook to edit the subject and body text using following code:

```
Sub SetupEmailTexts()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNameSpace As Object 'Outlook.NameSpace
Dim MailFolder As Object 'Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim MyMail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem

GetSetup

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MailFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(16)
Set MyMail = MailFolder.Items.Add
MyMail.Display
MyMail.Subject = SubjectString
MyMail.HTMLBody = BodyString
MsgBox ("Edit subject and body before pressing OK")
If Not IsNull(MyMail) Then
    PutSubjectBody MyMail.Subject, MyMail.HTMLBody
    MyMail.Close olDiscard
End If
End Sub
```

If I close outlook before pressing OK in the message box produced by the code, i receive the runtime error "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" in line "PutSubjectBody MyMail.Subject, MyMail.HTMLBody".
As You can see I have tried to use IsNull to determine MyMail is still "alive" or not.
What can I use instead of "IsNull"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use an `On Error`, detect that specific `Err.Number` and handle it gracefully.

The closure of the automation object is not going to be reflected in the state of the `MyMail` variable itself, it would need to implement a `IsConnectedToInstance` property, and it does not.

You could wire up the event `Outlook.Application.Quit` but then you would need to check a flag and there would be cases when it gets missed.

Comment: Ofcause! 
I havn't thought that way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use error handling -

add the line in the beginning of the sub

```
On Error goto err
```

add on the end of the sub:

```
NoError:
  exit sub

err:
    msgbox "you closed outlook. couldn't do my thing"
```